# Nested iif with multiple conditions SSRS

Tags: vba, reporting-services, formula, iif

I need to write a formula for a SSRS report.  I am not for sure about the exact syntax, but it I am thinking it should be a nested iif but with multiple criteria, checking the value of the chart and division fields. At the end of the day if chart=110300 and division=100 then "Intercompany AP - USA" or if chart=110300 and division=200 then "Intercompany AP - RUS" other wise, then just display the chartname.  Something like this but actually written correctly.

```
iif Fields!chart.Value="110300" and Fields!division.Value="100" then
Fields!chartname.Value="Intercompany AP - USA" if Fields!chart.Value="110300"
and Fields!division.Value="200" then Fields!chartname.Value=
"Intercompany AP - RUS" else Fields!chartname.Value
```

I greatly appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You pretty much solved this one yourself! To write this in T-SQL you right click the Chart Name and change its value to the following expression:

```
IIF(Fields!chart.Value="110300" AND Fields!division.Value="100","Intercompany AP - USA",IIF(Fields!chart.Value="110300" AND Fields!division.Value="200","Intercompany AP - RUS","Default Chart Name")
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213574.aspx) for explanation on how the IIF function works

From the link you can see that it takes the following format, where commas are used instead of "Then" or "Else":

`IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )`

So to breakdown the expression:

```
IIF(Fields!chart.Value="110300" AND Fields!division.Value="100",
    "Intercompany AP - USA",
     IIF(Fields!chart.Value="110300" AND Fields!division.Value="200",
        "Intercompany AP - RUS",
        "Default Chart Name"
     )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your heko @tom jenkin!!

Comment: Best answer ever! @Tom